Проблема с точкой входа в процедуру
Точка входа в процедуру DiscardVirtualMemory не найдена в
библиотеке DLL C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12.18-3.10\pgAdmin
4\runtime\nw.dll
Такую ошибку получил при запуске pgAdmin4 на сервере Windows8.1 сразу после установки, в процессе ошибок не вылетало,заранее благодарю за помощь

Свежие версии выше шестой не будут работать на Windows8.1 насколько я знаю это проблема связана с изменением API и загрузкой dll никак не решается я на этих версиях работаю на 6.21 по моему все дистрибы доступны берите 6 в общем.
